# Twitter oAuth login. How to get getAuthorizeURL(authorize) for first time and (authenticate) once user has granted permissions

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

I am using Twitter oAuth PHP Library (by Abraham Williams) for login-using-twitter for my web-application.

A.The Code model looks like this:

1.The Callback URL in twitter settings is set to :
http://example.com/entrypoint/twitterlogin.php

```
2.The twitterlogin.php file
<?PHP
    if (empty($_GET['oauth_verifier'])){        
        $request_token = $twitteroauth->getRequestToken();
        $_SESSION['onetime_oauth_token'] = $request_token['oauth_token'];
        $_SESSION['onetime_oauth_token_secret'] = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];
    }

    if (!empty($_GET['oauth_verifier']) && !empty($_SESSION['onetime_oauth_token']) && !empty($_SESSION['onetime_oauth_token_secret'])) {        
        $twitteroauth = new TwitterOAuth(YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY, YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET, $_SESSION['onetime_oauth_token'], $_SESSION['onetime_oauth_token_secret']);        
        $access_token = $twitteroauth->getAccessToken($_GET['oauth_verifier']);        
        $GoesToDB = $access_token['oauth_token'];
        $GoesToDBS = $access_token['oauth_token_secret'];
        $user_info = $twitteroauth->get('account/verify_credentials');
        $GoesToDBArray = $user_info;
    }else{        
        if ($twitteroauth->http_code == 200) {
            //generates ~/authenticate?oauth_token=token
            $url = $twitteroauth->getAuthorizeURL($request_token['oauth_token']);

            //generates ~/authorize?oauth_token=token
            //$url = $twitteroauth->getAuthorizeURL($request_token['oauth_token'], false);//when and how to use this
            exit(header("refresh:0;url=".$url));    
        } else {
            //some error handler        
        }
    }
?>
```

B.Expected behavior/results

1. If the user is first time user then generate authorize url (~/authorize?oauth_token=token)
2. Once the user has granted the permissions to the application generate authenticate url (~/authenticate?oauth_token=token) for future logins

C.Queries

1. Is the approach correct for the expected behavior
2. Do i have ask the user to use authorize url if he is an first time user, else use the authenticate url(similar the signin and signup)
3. Is there way to check if the user has authorized the application using (onetime_oauth_token or something else)

D.Thanking you in advance :) .. you are a life saviour.

Answer (score 0):

Use this -

```
$url = $twitteroauth->getAuthorizeURL($request_token['oauth_token'],TRUE);
```

Comment: Hello @sahil, thank-you for your response. My main concern was, how to use the  "True/False" parameter "Authenticate/Authorize"